# Dell XPS 410, 2007, Windows Vista Hard Drive is dead, How to copy all content including the OS into a new one

Tags: hard-drive

I think I have a Western Digital Hard Drive but I'm not sure. I don't even know how to open the thing up to check. I have the unit sitting in front of my laptop which I'm using to make this and it's saying

```
No boot device avalaible - strike the F1 key to retry boot, F2 for setup utility
```

Everything in the BIOS is fine, but I ran a diagnostic scan on the hard drive and it didn't even show up, the PC can't detect the hard drive. A few tries later it detected it and showed me this

```
(I forgot the long drive name) Fail - Return Code 3
```

I did some researching on that and it says that there is an unfixable error with the hard drive with something of it dying. You need to get a new hard disk to get it working.

I'm not reinstalling an unsupported Windows Vista, but I would like to keep all the files I have as they're somewhat important and I can't copy the 100GB used onto my memory sticks. The WiFi is broken so I cant do any kind of transfer to this PC using WiFi. There may be ways to send info to this PC.

So I need to know how to get rid of the junk inside it (the hard drive) but keep data and send it to a new one.

Comment: If the HDD has failed, you are out of luck, your not going to be able to duplicate the hdd at this point.  Given the resources you have available, what you want, isn't possible

Comment: Yea, if the drive is dead, you're out of luck unless you've got a load of money to pay for high-end data recovery. As Vylix mentions, you should take the computer to a reputable computer repair shop to get a more concrete diagnosis and to get your data back.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't open up your computer yourself, then go to a computer shop, and ask them to diagnose whether your harddisk is somehow still functioning. If it is, ask them to back up your files while it's still possible. If it's **not**, then you **must give up** your old harddisk.

To where you must back them up? The easiest is to an external harddisk, then you can proceed to transfer them to your other computer if you wish so.